# Find the equation of the line

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

I have to find the line that passes through $(3, 1, -2)$ and intersects under right angle the line $x=-1+t, y=-2+t, z=-1+t$.

(HINT: If $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ the intersection point, find the coordinates.)

I have done the following:

The line that passes through $(3, 1, -2)$ is of the form $$\overrightarrow{l}(t)=(3, 1, -2)+t\overrightarrow{u}$$ where $\overrightarrow{u}$ is a vector parallel to the line.

Let $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ be the intersection point of the line $\overrightarrow{l}$ and the line $x=-1+t, y=-2+t, z=-1+t$, then we have the folowing:

$$x_0=3+tu_1=-1+t, \\ y_0=1+tu_2=-2+t, \\ z_0=-2+tu_3=-1+t$$

Is it correct so far??

How could I continue??

Do we have to use the fact that the two lines intersect under right angle??

Comment: won't there be lots of lines in the plane $x + y + z = 2?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you want to use another parameter besides t for the second line.

Using s instead, we have the equations

$x_0=3+su_1=-1+t,\;\; y_0=1+su_2=-2+t,\;\; z_0=-2+su_3=-1+t$.

Since the lines are perpendicular, we have that $\langle1,1,1\rangle\cdot\langle u_1,u_2,u_3\rangle=u_1+u_2+u_3=0$.

Adding the 3 equations gives $2=-4+3t$, so $t=2$ and the lines intersect at $(1,0,1)$.

Thus we can take $\langle u_1,u_2,u_3\rangle=\langle2,1,-3\rangle$, so the second line has parametric equations

$x=3+2s,\;\; y=1+s,\;\; z=-2-3s$.

---

Alternate solution:

The plane which is perpendicular to the given line and passes through $(3,1,-2)$ has equation

$\;\;\;x+y+z=2$, so the plane and line intersect where

$\;\;\;(-1+t)+(-2+t)+(-1+t)=2$, so $3t=6$ and $t=2$.

Then $(1,0,1)$ is the point of intersection, so the perpendicular line we want is parallel to

$\vec{u}=\langle3-1,1-0,-2-1\rangle=\langle2,1,-3\rangle$; and therefore it has parametric equations

$x=3+2s,\;\; y=1+s,\;\; z=-2-3s$.

Comment: I see!! Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use those equations to find the direction vector $\vec{u}$.
Since there are four variables, $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$, and $t$, you will need one more equation relating them. For this, note that the two lines will be perpendicular to each other, so $\vec{u}\cdot\langle 1, 1, 1 \rangle = 0$. In other words, $u_1 + u_2 + u_3 = 0$. Then you can solve the system and substitute *t* into the original line equations to find the point of intersection. (You could solve the original equations for each component of *u*, then substitute them into the dot product equation and solve for *t*.)

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest mistake is that you've used $t$ in the equations for both lines. This causes problems when you try to find intersection points, since it's not certain that at the intersection point the $t$ for one line is the same as the $t$ for the other line. For that reason you should use $s$ or something else for one of the lines.

Assume they intersect at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. Then you know two points of the line $\vec l$, so use those to parametrize it:
$$
\vec l (s) = s\cdot (3, 1, -2) + (1-s)\cdot (x_0, y_0, z_0) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + s\cdot (3-x_0, 1-y_0, -2-z_0)
$$
What do we know about $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$? Well, we know that it lies on the other line. Therefore there is a $t_0$ such that $(x_0, y_0, z_0) = (-1+t_0, -2 + t_0, -1 + t_0)$ (that is what it means to say that that point lies on that line). If we insert this into our equation for $\vec l$, we get
$$
\vec l (s) = (-1+t_0, -2 + t_0, -1 + t_0) + s\cdot (3-(-1+t_0), 1-(-2 + t_0), -2-(-1 + t_0)) \\
= (-1+t_0, -2 + t_0, -1 + t_0) + s\cdot (4-t_0, 3- t_0, -1- t_0)
$$
Now we need to decide $t_0$, and we do that by using the right-angle condition. If there were no right-angle condition, then we would be done here, and *any* $t_0$ would work and give us a line that goes through the point we want it to, and intersects the line we want it to intersect.

But we have to find the right $t_0$ to make $(1, 1, 1)$ stand at a right angle to $(4-t_0, 3- t_0, -1- t_0)$, which we can express as
$$
(1, 1, 1)\cdot (4-t_0, 3- t_0, -1- t_0) = 0\\
4-t_0+ 3- t_0+ -1- t_0 = 0\\
6 = 3t_0\\
t_0 = 2
$$
Using this we finally get that the line $\vec l$ is given by
$$
\vec l (s) = (-1+2, -2 + 2, -1 + 2) + s\cdot (4-2, 3- 2, -1- 2)\\
= (1, 0, 1) + s\cdot (2, 1, -3)
$$

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)